# How to emit event when using snack-bar (entryComponents) in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Here I had a method 'confirmSth', loaded a component 'SnackCheckBoxComponent' dynamically.

I would like to know If I can get some msg in my OrderDetailComponent to distinguish which button from SnackCheckBoxComponent i clicked so to decide 
 the confirmSth return true or false.

```
//...
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

export class OrderDetailComponent {

  constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {

  confirmSth(): boolean {

    // ...condition
    if (condition) return true

    this.snackBarRef = this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackCheckBoxComponent, { duration: 50000 })
    this.snackBarRef.instance.snackBarRefCheckComponent = this.snackBarRef

    // I would like to know If I can get some msg here to distinguish which button i clicked so to decide return true or false.

  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'snack-check-box',
  templateUrl: './snack-check-box.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-check-box.css'],
})
export class SnackCheckBoxComponent {
  public snackBarRefCheckComponent: MdSnackBarRef<SnackCheckBoxComponent>

  private onCancel() {
    alert('clicked option 1');
    this.snackBarRefCheckComponent.dismiss();
  }

  private onSubmit() {
    alert('clicked option 2');
    this.snackBarRefCheckComponent.dismiss();
  }
}
```

here is my './snack-check-box.html'

```
<span>overloaded, whether to continue xxx</span>

<a (click)="onSubmit()">yes</a>
<a (click)="onCancel()">no</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two RxJS subjects inside the `SnackCheckBoxComponent` and invoke a `next` value using your bound functions; here's an example with only submit functionality.

```
export class SnackCheckBoxComponent {
  public submit$ = new Subject<void>()
  public onSubmit() { this.submit$.next(null) }
}
```

Now from your `OrderDetailComponent`, you can subscribe to these events:

```
this.snackBarRef.instance.submit$.take(1).subscribe(() => {
  // handle submission here
}
```

Note that since I've used `.take(1)` you do not have to manually unsubscribe from this subscription. The stream will end after taking one and only item which we expect. Alternatively, you could use `Observable#toPromise` here.

---

As a side note, your `onCancel` and `onSubmit` must be `public` since you're accessing them from the template (outside the class). Templates are currently not type-checked in JIT mode, but your code would fail in AOT which is becoming a standard for Angular applications.

Comment: thanks for solving my problem, It works! I don't know Subject until you told me, haha, I'm going to search more about this. And my function are `public` now, thank you!